# Dynamic Programming - Number of ways to make a building

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am attempting to solve a problem of the following kind using dynamic programming - I can't seem to find the recurrence. The problem is as follows :

"A building is a structure formed by a pile of at least two blocks.

Your task is to find total ways, such that all blocks are utilized in making buildings.

For example, for n = 5 the answer is 2 because [5] , [2 , 3] .

For n = 6 the answer is 4 because [6] , [2 , 4] , [2 ,2 ,2] , [3 ,3]"

Can someone help me understand how to do this from a bottom up or top down manner?

Comment: what `n` is supposed to mean?

Comment: n is the number of blocks

Comment: (1) Dynamic programming helps to find an optimal solution, not expanding all possibilities.   (2) Why not 5 isn't 7 combinations of [5], [1,4], [1,1,3], [1,1,1,2], [1,1,1,1,1], [2,3], [2,1,2] ?  And how is this related to "A building is a structure formed ..." ?

Comment: @KenCheung The minimum size must be 2 (and not 1)

Comment: That is not the correct answer because a building is supposed to consist of 2 blocks so [1 ,4 ] is invalid because the first term is less than 2

Comment: While it's not exactly the same, this is very similar to the integer partition problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory) could provide some insights.

Comment: I read the question, I read the comments. The question needs to be edited. Can `[1]` be used? is there a minimum of two blocks? is the order of the blocks significant? please clarify the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has the same idea as the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem). Let `f[i][j]` detone the number of partitions of `i` in blocks of non-decreasing size such that the last block size is `j`. Your update rule, then, would be:

```
f[i+k][k] += f[i][j], for k>= max(2, j) // bottom-up approach
```

and the answer for the number of partitions:

```
f[n][2] + f[n][3] + ... + f[n][n]
```

Alternatively, you could use top-down approach:

```
f[i][j] += f[i-k][k] for 2 <= k <= j
```

Running this on your examples you have:

```
Initialize f[i][i] = 1, i >= 2 and the rest set to 0

f[2][2] = 1

f[3][2] = f[1][2] = 0
f[3][3] = 1

f[4][2] = f[2][2] = 1
f[4][3] = f[1][2] + f[1][3] = 0
f[4][4] = 1

f[5][2] = f[3][2] = 0
f[5][3] = f[2][2] + f[2][3] = 1
f[5][4] = f[1][2] + f[1][3] + f[1][4] = 0
f[5][5] = 1


f[6][2] = f[4][2] = 1
f[6][3] = f[3][2] + f[3][3] = 1
f[6][4] = f[2][2] + f[2][3] + f[2][4] = 1
f[6][5] = f[1][2] + f[1][3] + f[1][4] + f[1][5] = 0
f[6][6] = 1

count(5) = f[5][2] + f[5][3] + f[5][4] + f[5][5] = 2
count(6) = f[6][2] + f[6][3] + f[6][4] + f[6][5] + f[6][6] = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a really simple solution to this: the number of partitions of `n` that contain a `1` equals the total number of partitions of `(n - 1)`. One way to think of it is imagining removing one `1` from each of the partitions of `n` that contain one; any partition of `n` that does not contain a `1` cannot be transformed in such a way.

So we can simply remove the first term from the classic [partition recurrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Recurrence_formula),  `p(k) = p(k − 1) + p(k − 2) − p(k − 5) − p(k − 7) + p(k − 12) + p(k − 15) − p(k − 22) − ...`, and derive:

```
p_without_1s(k) = p(k − 2) − p(k − 5) − p(k − 7) + p(k − 12) + p(k − 15) − p(k − 22) − ...
```

Or

```
p_without_1s(k) = p(k) - p(k - 1)
```